# How do I change the environment texture on blender using the python api?

Tags: python, rendering, blender

I want to change my world's environment texture on blender 2.8. I have to do this multiple times so I want to use the Python API to save time. I am using nodes but I am not sure how I can assign an HDR image to the ['Environment Texture'] node. Thank you!

Comment: Look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132271/blender-2-8-get-environment-texture-path-from-ui-to-python-script